# Selecionar registro de cada categoria mysql

Tags: mysqli, php-7.1

Como eu faço para pegar os dois registros com maior visualização de cada categoria? Eu tenho 7 categorias e gostaria de pegar os dois itens com maior visualizações de cada uma dessas 7 categorias.

Comment: Orderna por visualização, se for necessário agrupe as categoria,  Order by visualização desc

Comment: A ordenação eu sei fazer, mas como eu vou fazer query e pegar os dois itens de cada categoria? E claro, se houver mais que um item em cada categoria, pq eu posso ter apenas um registro na categoria A e 15 na categoria B. Terá que retornar um registro da categoria A e dois da categoria B.

Comment: pegar os dois maiores , por categoria. Essa visualização vem em cada linha junto com a categoria